# Invalidating email addresses from sql dump before import

Tags: regex, mysql, grep, sed, awk

## Synopsis

I would like to import production data into the development environment so testing can be done in an almost accurate way. Of course I need to invalidate e-mail addresses as I don't want e-mails reaching the end-user.

## Source

*Just a side note - my expression deliberately matches ['] as part of the query syntax*

So far I have the following using `grep` which was to test my expression.

```
$ cat site_backup.sql | egrep -io '\w+([._-]\w*)@\w+([._-]\w*)\.\w{2,4}'
```

This is printing the e-mail addresses, but of course I need to replace using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r -e "s/'(\w+)([._-]\w*)@(\w+)([._-]\w*)(\.\w{2,4})'/\1\2@invalid.\3\4\5/g" -i site_backup.sql
```

Works fine on a small percentage of e-mail addresses; I've noticed a pattern in what was not replaced `'word@word.ex.t'`

## Conclusion

After appending another expression for this, it has no affect.  I still haven't looked into `awk` which I know is very powerful so i'm not ignorant to it, i'm hoping someone could help.

My goal is simple, I am using `mysqldump` to export a production database, I then wish to replace all e-mail addresses (or as many as reasonably possible) before importing the data in to the development environment.  Am I possibly doing this from an awkward angle?

Comment: It would be nice if you could segregate the email addresses before you export.. but if you can't, try this regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: You could just import it (possibly into a dummy) first and then change the emails as it simplifies the action since you now have column access. Also, this is off topic for serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

Import your dump into a new database and use a query like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET email_field_name = REPLACE(email_field_name, '@', '@invalid.');
```

Comment: I don't think this is appropriate because there are a number of tables that contain e-mail addresses, more-so orders, customers and newsletter subscribers.  Also I was hoping I could use [tag:bash] for this.  Looking at the sql dump It's a file of characters, I presume although long-winded my regex needs to be fine-tuned to match an *expression* similar to a quoted string; containing exactly one @ symbol followed by a further word.  I don't believe this task is for the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18355644/1690631

Thanks to [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava).